# Converting multiple files in a directory into .txt format. But file names become Binary

Tags: python-3.x, directory, nlp, operating-system

So I am creating plagiarism software, for that, I need to convert .pdf, .docx,[enter image description here][1] etc files into a .txt format. I successfully found a way to convert all the files in one directory to another. BUT the problem is, this method is changing the file names

[image: file names]

into binary values. I need to get the original file name which I am gonna need in the next phase.

[image]

```
**Code:**
import os
import uuid
import textract
source_directory = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "C:/Users/syedm/Desktop/Study/FOUNDplag/Plagiarism-checker-Python/mainfolder")

for filename in os.listdir(source_directory):
    file, extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
    unique_filename = str(uuid.uuid4()) + extension
    os.rename(os.path.join(source_directory,  filename), os.path.join(source_directory, unique_filename))

training_directory = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "C:/Users/syedm/Desktop/Study/FOUNDplag/Plagiarism-checker-Python/trainingdata")

for process_file in os.listdir(source_directory):
    file, extension = os.path.splitext(process_file)

    # We create a new text file name by concatenating the .txt extension to file UUID
    dest_file_path = file + '.txt'

    # extract text from the file
    content = textract.process(os.path.join(source_directory, process_file))

    # We create and open the new and we prepare to write the Binary Data which is represented by the wb - Write Binary
    write_text_file = open(os.path.join(training_directory, dest_file_path), "wb")

    # write the content and close the newly created file
    write_text_file.write(content)
    write_text_file.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove this line where you rename the files:

```
os.rename(os.path.join(source_directory,  filename), os.path.join(source_directory, unique_filename))
```

that's also not binary, but a [uuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) instead.

Cheers